# App Engine standard vs. flexible min instances

Tags: google-app-engine

Running an app in the standard environment with `instance_class: F2` (`512 MB`/`1.2 GHz`), `min_instances: 1`, `max_instances: 3` it almost always runs with 2 or 3 active/billed instances, rarely dropping to 1.

Attempting to match the config above in the flexible environment, if I run the app with `cpu: 1`, `memory_gb: 0.5`, `max_num_instances: 3` it runs most of the time with only a single instance active, halving the cost.

Without having to resort to `max_instances: 1` is there a way to configure the standard environment to bring it more inline with the flexible? I've tried using `target_cpu_utilization` and `max_concurrent_requests`. E.g. `target_cpu_utilization: 0.8`, `max_concurrent_requests: 80` but this makes no difference.

Comment: I will depend on your memory usage and use case. I would recommend that if you are using less than 512 MB memory limit and 1.2 GHz CPU limit, you can [downgrade](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes) to B1 (256 MB and 600 MHz), which provides you with more flexibility for scaling, includes [manual and basic scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements), plus it will be [cheaper](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing). As for your main question, I am not aware of any method to make it similar to Flex config.

Comment: In my case I can't downgrade because some processes require the extra RAM. My main issue is that standard never seems to run on only a single instance regardless of the traffic, it seems much more eager to use more instances no matter the config.

Comment: In this case, you can use B2, which offers you (512 MB Memory Limit and 1.2 GHz CPU Limit) and is the same performance with the difference that B2 supports manual and basic scaling types. This will give you more flexibility for your instance settings and scaling options. The last option would be to check out the pros and cons of migrating to App Engine flexible since you already know that your use case might fit better there. Hope this helps.